# Move specific files by extension into folder and rename dublicates if any

Tags: command-line, python

So basically I have multiple .txt files in folders and subfolders which I want to move to new folder.

Although some files are with the same name, they might have different content, so I would like to keep them all, but renamed.

What I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shutil

source_dir = "/home/source_folder"; target_folder = "/home/target_folder"; extensions = (".txt",)

dup = 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(extensions):
            file = root+"/"+name
            while os.path.exists(target_folder+"/"+name):
                name = name[:name.rfind(".")]+"_"+str(dup)+name[name.rfind("."):]
                dup = dup+1
            shutil.move(file, target_folder+"/"+name)
```

**The problem** - all files are renamed with numbers, not only duplicates.
Perfect solution would be **date hierarchy to be added to the name only** for the duplicates.

Any fix to this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I know to little of python to get you a script, but I did a similar script in bash in the past. So for each file look for a file that already exist. If it doesn't, simply move it. If it does, compare the checksum (sha1 is fast enought I'd say) of each file. If they're the same, do nothing, if they're different, move it with a suffix

Answer (score 0):

First, I will show you the directory structure. I am moving `txt` files from `src1` to `dest1`

```
.
├── dest1
└── src1
    ├── abc.txt
    ├── adx.txt
    ├── logs
    │   ├── nft.txt
    │   ├── orm.txt
    │   └── yuy
    ├── lol
    ├── nft.txt
    ├── orm.txt
    └── yuy
```

You can use the command

```
find src1/ -regextype sed -regex '.*/*\.txt' -exec mv --backup=t -t dest1/ {} +
```

Where `src1` is the source folder containing `txt` files and `dst1` is the destination folder. If in case file with the same name exist, the file name will be suffixed with `.~1~`

```
.
├── dest1
│   ├── abc.txt
│   ├── adx.txt
│   ├── nft.txt
│   ├── nft.txt.~1~
│   ├── orm.txt
│   └── orm.txt.~1~
└── src1
    ├── logs
    │   └── yuy
    ├── lol
    └── yuy
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It seems sufficient command, but I would like python alternative also, to be cross platform.

Anyway, I used your command and it is awesome !!! Thanks again!

Comment: That's great. Please tell me what should the file be renamed as (instead of that `.~1~` suffix) and I'll help with the full command